# javascript dynamically add columns add rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which I want users to be able to add rows and columns each cell contains a Text box or textarea.

I can add rows perfectly however i cannot add columns.

JS code

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    if(rowCount < 5){
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML code

```
<legend>Work Experience</legend>
<fieldset class="row6"><p>
    <input type="button" value="Add Work Experience" onClick="addRow('workexperienceTable')" />
    <input type="button" value="Remove Work Experience" onClick="deleteRow('workexperienceTable')"  />
    <p>(All acions apply only to entries with check marked check boxes only.)</p></p>
    <table id="workexperienceTable" class="form" border="1"><tbody><tr><p>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
        <td><label>Job Title</label><input  type="text" name="jobtitle[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br></td>
        <td><label>Company Name</label><input  type="text" name="companyname[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br></td>
        <td><label>Company Location</label>
        <input  type="text" name="cstreet[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br>
        <input  type="text" name="ccity[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br>
        <input  type="text" name="cstate[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br>
        <td><p>Please Select Your Start Date<input type="text" name="sdate[]" id="datepicker1"></p></td>
        <td><p>Please Select Your End Date<input type="text" name="edate[]" id="datepicker2"></p></td>
        <td><label>Short Description of what your did</label><input  type="text" name="jobdesc[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br></td>
        <td><label>Job Duties(Do not and any formatting or bullets. One line per Job Duty</label><textarea name="jobduty[]" style="width:600px;height:120px;"></textarea><br></td>
        <td><label>Technologies Used(Do not and any formatting or bullets. One line per Job Duty</label><textarea name="techused[]" style="width:600px;height:120px;"></textarea><br></td>
    </p></tr></tbody></table>
```

If i use the above code everything will work fine until i put in a

```
</tr>
<tr>
```

To break out to a new row.

I have a tried a couple different ways to get the columns to add.

```
<input  type="text" name="cstate[]" maxlength="30" size="30"><br>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><p>Please Select Your Start Date<input type="text" name="sdate[]" id="datepicker1"></p></td>

for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    var newcol = row.insertCol(i);
    newcol.innerHTML = table.cols[0].rows[i].cells[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction.

http://jsfiddle.net/h0t61Lx9/

Comment: What should be in the new column?

Comment: Pay attention to the syntax highlighting in your jsfiddle. It will point out several unclosed tags.

Comment: The new column should start a new row with the rest of the form as described. last cell of row 1 col X has cstate[] row 2 of col X has sdate[] and I would Two new rows use colspan to get the  jobduty[] and techused[]

Comment: I don't understand. A new column can't start a new row, it's a column in an existing row. Can you show what you want the HTML to look like after the new column is added?

Comment: What i would like it look like. http://jsfiddle.net/yc44sgm3/ Then when add Work Experience is clicked the whole table get created again.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use something like Slickgrid.
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

However, can you not do something like this, with plain javascript? (I'm also using JQuery here, but I think this could be done without, just a little more verbose)

```
function addColumn(tableid, defaultContents)
{
    var table = $("#" + tableid);

    var tbody = $(table[0]).children("tbody");

    var rows = $(tbody[0]).children("tr");

    for(var i=0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        var cell = $("<td>" + defaultContents + "</td>");

        $(rows[i]).append(cell);
    }
}
```

Obviously, you might want to make it a little more elaborate, to add a column heading and so for, but this definitely works on IE11, Firefox and Chrome.